# rspec/minitest for Ruby: How to turn an array of objects into individual tests?

Tags: ruby, json, rspec, minitest

I'm writing a parser for a small language that has test specs formatted in JSON, effectively like this:

```
[ {"input":"foo", "output":"bar"}, 
  {"input":"baz", "output":"boo"},
  ...]
```

Assuming I've parsed the JSON into an array of hashes, how would I write a spec that would use the `input` as a descriptor and test my library against each `output`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply iterate over the hash. You've got a few choices:

```
inputs_and_outputs = [
  { 'input' => 'a', 'output' => 'x' },
  { 'input' => 'b', 'output' => 'y' }
]
```

**Standard Minitest**

```
# One test with multiple assertions
def test_that_it_returns_the_expected_outputs
  inputs_and_outputs.each do |input_output|
    input = input_output['input']
    output = input_output['output']

    assert_equal output, your_function(input)
  end
end


# Separate test per input output
inputs_and_outputs.each do |input_output|
  input = input_output['input']
  output = input_output['output']

  define_method("test_returns_#{output}_given_#{input}") do
    assert_equal output, your_function(input)
  end
end
```

**Minitest Spec**

```
# One test with multiple assertions
it "returns the expected outputs" do
  inputs_and_outputs.each do |input_output|
    input = input_output['input']
    output = input_output['output']

    assert_equal output, your_function(input)
  end
end

# Separate test per input output
inputs_and_outputs.each do |input_output|
  input = input_output['input']
  output = input_output['output']

  it "returns #{output} given #{input}" do
    assert_equal output, your_function(input)
  end
end
```

Comment: I thought I had accepted your answer weeks ago... thanks for being so thorough!